# Relationship between Hadamard and Inner Product

Tags: vectors, inner-products, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

Suppose I have two scalars $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ defined by the inner products:

$$ a = \mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{t} $$ 
$$ b = \mathbf{b}^{T} \mathbf{t} $$

where $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{t} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$. Can I represent their product as:

$$a \cdot b = (\mathbf{a}^{T} \mathbf{t})(\mathbf{b}^{T} \mathbf{t}) $$
$$\boxed{a \cdot b = (\mathbf{a}^{T} \circ \mathbf{b}^{T})\mathbf{t}} $$

Or is there some kind of other relation?

---

**Update:**

@greg Has pointed out that this is valid only when $\mathbf{t}$ is the all zero  vector, or a coordinate vector. So my next question is:

**What is the relation between these two quantities for a general $\mathbf{t}$?**

---

**Answer:**

In general, we have:

$$ \boxed{a \cdot b = \mathbf{1}^{T} \left( \left( \mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b} \right) \circ \left(\mathbf{t} \otimes \mathbf{t} \right)    \right) \mathbf{1}} $$

Comment: This is only true if $t$ is one of the standard basis vectors $\{e_k\},\,$ or the zero vector.

Comment: @greg Thank you for confirming. I wrote out a bunch of counter examples and that seems to be what I found.

Comment: @greg Would you know what the relationship would be for general $\mathbf{t}$?

Comment: For Hadamard products and vectors the only rules (that I'm aware of) are:
$$\eqalign{
&(a\otimes b)\circ(x\otimes y) &= (a\circ x)\otimes(b\circ y) \\
&(a\circ b)\circ(x\circ y) &= (a\circ b\circ x\circ y) \\
&(a\circ b)^T(x\circ y) &= a^T(b\circ x\circ y) \\
&(ab^T)\circ(xy^T) &= (a\circ x)(b\circ y)^T \\
}$$
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

Comment: @greg Cool thanks that is super helpful

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the relation in the box is generally valid.  Here is a simple counterexample below.  I hope this helps.

$$
\textbf{a} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 \\ 2
\end{pmatrix},
\textbf{b} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
3 \\ 4
\end{pmatrix},
\textbf{t} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 \\ 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\textbf{a}^{T}\textbf{t}=a=2+6=8 \\ 
\textbf{b}^{T}\textbf{t}=b=6+12=18 \\
a \cdot b = 8(18) = 144
$$

$$
\textbf{a}^T \circ \textbf{b}^T  = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 8
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\left( \textbf{a}^T \circ \textbf{b}^T \right) \textbf{t} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
3 & 8
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 \\ 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
6+24=30 \ne 144
$$